# Inserting space between specific characters/words

Tags: vb.net

I have the following string:

```
15 + power ( 10,5 ) + 5 + power ( 1,5 )
```

My goal would be to put a space between the commas, ending up with a string as follow:

```
15 + power ( 10 , 5 ) + 5 + power ( 1 , 5 )
```

I have tried splitting the string by whitespace, and getting the index of the "power"s (inputtedString being the first line of code):

```
"15 + power ( 10,5 ) + 5 + power ( 1,5 )".Split(" ").Select(Function(b, i) If(b = "power", i, -1)).Where(Function(i) i <> -1)
```

However, I'm having trouble continuing: Even if I were to split 10,5 into 10 and 5, I couldn't insert it to the list within a foreach loop.

I presume I could create a dictionary to store these to-be-modified and to-be-inserted items to the list, or create a new list within the foreach loop, but I don't think this is the cleanest and easiest way to solve this issue.

**Edit1:** I can't use string.Replace(",", " , "), as I must only modify the values inside the 'power()' tags

Comment: strYourString.Replace(",", " , ") ?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to only change the values inside the power() tag, I can't replace all commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following solution:

```
Dim str As String = "15 + power ( 10,5 ) + 5 + power ( 1,5 )"
Dim rgx As New Regex("([ ]*),([ ]*)")
Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(str, " , ")
Debug.Print(result) '15 + power ( 10 , 5 ) + 5 + power ( 1 , 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure Sebastian's answer is excellent but I am not yet comfortable with Regex, so I have one without regex also in 2 lines of code.

```
Private Sub btnAddSpaces_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddSpaces.Click
        Dim OriginalString As String = "15 + power ( 10,5 ) + 5 + power ( 1,5 )"
        Dim StringArray() As String = OriginalString.Split(","c)
        Dim NewString As String = Join(StringArray, " , ")
        Debug.Print(NewString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I can't replace every comma in the string, I need to only replace the ones within power()s.